# Push "programmatic" array to an Object's array property

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, nosql

I'm building a Thesaurus app, and for this question, the key note is that i'm adding a list of synonyms(words that have the same meaning) for a particular word(eg - "feline", "tomcat", "puss" are synonyms of "cat")

I have a Word object, with a property - "synonyms" - which is an array.
I'm going to add an array of synonyms to the Word synonyms property.
According to the MongoDb documentation [see here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/), the only way to append all the indexes of an array to a document's array property at once is to try the following:

```
db.students.update(
   { _id: 5 },
   {
     $push: {
       quizzes: {
          $each: [ { wk: 5, score: 8 }, { wk: 6, score: 7 }, { wk: 7, score: 6 } ],
       }
     }
   }
)
```

Let's re-write that solution to suit my data, before we venture further.

```
db.words.update(
       { baseWord: 'cat' },
       {
         $push: {
           synonyms: {
              $each: [ { _id: 'someValue', synonym: 'feline' }, { _id: 'someValue', synonym: 'puss' }, { _id: 'someValue', synonym: 'tomcat' } ],
           }
         }
       }
    )
```

Nice and concise, but not what i'm trying to do.

What if you don't know your data beforehand and have a dynamic array which you'd like to feed in?
My current solution is to split up the array and run a forEach() loop, resulting in an array being appended to the Word object's synonyms array property like so:

```
//req.body.synonym = 'feline,tomcat,puss';
var individualSynonyms = req.body.synonym.split(',');

individualSynonyms.forEach(function(synonym) {

            db.words.update(                                
                { "_id": 5 },                       
                {  $push:  //this is the Word.synonyms
                    {   synonyms: 
                        {   
                        $each:[{ //pushing each synonym as a Synonym object                     
                                uuid : uuid.v4(),                                       
                                synonym:synonym,                                    
                            }]                                  
                        }   
                    }  
                },{ upsert : true },
                function(err, result) {
                    if (err){
                        res.json({  success:false, message:'Error adding base word and synonym, try again or come back later.'  });
                        console.log("Error updating word and synonym document");
                    }
                    //using an 'else' clause here will flag a "multiple header" error due to multiple json messages being returned
                    //because of the forEach loop
                    /*
                    else{                               
                        res.json({  success:true, message:'Word and synonyms added!'    });
                        console.log("Update of Word document successful, check document list");
                    }
                    */             
                }); 
                //if each insert happen, we reach here
                if (!err){
                    res.json({  success:true, message:'Word and synonyms added!.'   });
                    console.log("Update of Word document successful, check document list");
                }       
        });
}
```

- This works as intended, but you may notice and issue at the bottom, where there's a commented out ELSE clause, and a check for 'if(!err)'.
  If the ELSE clause is executed, we get a "multiple headers" error because the loop causes multiple JSON results for a single request.

As well as that, 'if(!err)' will throw an error, because it doesn't have scope to the 'err' parameter in the callback from the .update() function. 
- If there was a way to avoid using a forEach loop, and directly feed the array of synonyms into a single update() call, then I can make use of if(!err) inside the callback.

You might be thinking: "Just remove the 'if(!err)' clause", but it seems unclean to just send a JSON response without some sort of final error check beforehand, whether an if, else, else if etc..

I could not find this particular approach in the documentation or on this site, and to me it seems like best practice if it can be done, as it allows you to perform a final error check before sending the response.
I'm curious about whether this can actually be done.

I'm not using the console, but I included a namespace prefix before calling each object for easier reading.

Comment: There's one thing that the answer doesn't address, that i'd like to know if possible. I'll accept the answer regardless as it was very helpful.
In my posted question, each synonym that's posted to the synonyms array receives a uuid property as well as its synonym property(representing that word we're adding to the 'Word' object).
In your solution, these synonyms that are being added no longer have a uuid. I realised soon after your last post that there was no need for me to issue uuids to those nested properties, but i'm curious if it can be done regardless.

Comment: Dude. I'm showing you adding the uuid as well. I'm basically doing everything your code was, except correctly. If you have questions, then come forward and ask them. Don't sit around silently for days.

Comment: A sample output for a Word entry is:
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59c2fae359bf1ed0fb70d83e"), "uuid" : "someValue", "baseWord" : "aaa", "synonyms" : [ { "synonym" : "bbb" }, { "synonym" : "ccc" }, { "synonym" : "ddd" } ], "__v" : 0 }

rather than say 

{ "_id" : ObjectId("59c2fae359bf1ed0fb70d83e"), "uuid" : "someValue", "baseWord" : "aaa", "synonyms" : [ { uuid: "someValue", "synonym" : "bbb" }, { uuid: "someValue", "synonym" : "ccc" }, { uuid: "someValue", "synonym" : "ddd" } ], "__v" : 0 }

Just trying to find the right trade-off between being inquisitive and a pest Neil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not need to "iterate" since [`$each`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/each/) takes an "array" as the argument. Simply [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the produced array from [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) with the additional data:

```
db.words.update(                                
  { "_id": 5 },                       
  {  $push: {
    synonyms: {   
      $each: req.body.synonym.split(',').map(synonym =>
        ({ uuid: uuid.v4, synonym })
      ) 
    }
  }},
  { upsert : true },
  function(err,result) {
    if (!err){
      res.json({  success:true, message:'Word and synonyms added!.'   });
      console.log("Update of Word document successful, check document list");
    }       
  }
);
```

So [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) produces an "array" from the string, which you "transform" using [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) into an array of the `uuid` value and the `"synonym"` from the elements of [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split). This is then a direct "array" to be applied with [`$each`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/each/) to the [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operation.

One request.